Какое свойство используется для flexbox чтобы выровнять блок по центру относительно главной оси персонально (по типу align-self)?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="third-block">
        <div class="white-block">
        </div>
        <div class="black-block">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


.white-block{
    height: 1037px;
    width: 664px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    align-self: center;
}
.third-block{
    height: 1277px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 220px;
    background-color: #E9E9E3;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.black-block{
    height: 1037px;
    width: 664px;
    background-color: #000000;
    align-self: center;
}

